# Logistic regression Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I have a dataset of 300 respondents (hours studied vs grade), I load the dataset in Excel run the data analysis add-in and run a linear regression. I get my results.

So the question is, Am I doing a Statistical Analysis or Am I doing Machine Learning? I know the question may seem simple but I think we should get some debate from this.

Comment: Both.  Regression and classification both fall into the machine learning/AI bucket.  Two algorithms among many, including neural networks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your question is better suited for [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) as it is not a question related to app/program development. Running formulas in excel through an add on is not really considered anywhere close to "programming".

Comment: "Excel is not really considered anywhere close to "programming"" - That's not true. Excel features fully-fledged programming language and is Turing complete.

Comment: @Lukasz Tracewski thank you for your comment. Generally speaking Excel is a program per se and not really a programming language. I rephrased either way in saying that running a formula through an add on is not really programming, as my main (and only point if you want) is that this kind of question is not really suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: If you want to do Logistic Regression using *sklearn* in Python 3.X, refer to https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

Answer (score 0):

Statistical Analysis is when you take statistical metrics of your data, like mean, standard deviation, confidence intervall, p-value...

Supervised Machine Learning is when you try to classify or predict something. For these problemns you use features as input to the model in order to classify a class or predict a value.

In this case you are doing machine learning, because you use the hours studied feature to predict the student grade.

Answer (score 0):

In the proper context, you're actually doing Statistical Analysis... (Which is part of Machine Learn